# Old construction, replacing light switch, bundled ground

Tags: switch, ground

I am replacing the light switch in my old home (1981). I can see that all grounds are at the back bundled together. Do I still have to legally connect the ground to the light switches' ground screw?

PS: The light on the ceiling is properly connected to the ground.

[image: Image attached]

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Modern code requires switches to be grounded. If you are not using self grounding switches and metal boxes (and you are not), you need to run a wire from the switch ground screw to the bundle.  Attaching to the end of any one of those wire will do.

**Supplement:** While the electrical police are unlikely to come pounding on your door, there is a reason for code. The ground serves as a safety if the switch gets damaged. It prevents the (rare) chance of you flicking a damaged switch and getting a shock. It's worth the trouble. In general, when you do an upgrade or a fix, you bring the device or system up to code if it is possible and reasonable. In this case it is both.

Comment: Does the legal requirement apply also for old construction? I've seen many houses that do not even have wiring in the walls that has a ground.

Comment: @Michael -- since there's a ground wire there, you have to connect to it.

Comment: Rare? I've had it happen to me.   And 1981 isn't old.  Grounding came in in the 60‘s.

Comment: Will it be okay if I pull the ground from spare romex that I have and loop it around the existing bundle and then to the screw? Normally I would use the plastic screw top to merge wires together but since these are already bundled using a copper compression thingy, I wonder what would be the best way to connect the ground to the screw.

Comment: Wrapping is not likely to be sufficient. You need a wire nut or a push in connector or a crimp connector to be sure of a real bond. It looks as if the bundle has ends  that could be flared a bit to accommodate.  Check the electrical connections aisle of your hardware store for one that would fit. It does not need to be insulated.

Comment: The push in connector looks like it could work. Btw, can I just unbundled the existing bundle without damaging the wires? That may simplify things.

Comment: Yes, you are totally welcome to unbundle the existing ground pack and use a wire nut on it.  Red or green wire nut would be just right.  Ideal is a great brand of wire nuts, Gardner Bender is everywhere but is meh.

Comment: Is there any advantage to having switches be grounded rather than double insulated?  Grounding protects exposed metal that a person might accidentally touch, but what if there's no metal anyway?

Comment: I think the metal yolk on the switches, often coupled with a metal faceplate, would make true double insulating difficult. Tools and devices that are double grounded are not meant to have user added parts that might compromise the safety.